# How to preserve select2 values after page reload in laravel 5.2?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, jquery-select2

In MVC project, based on laravel 5.2, for preserving values (not keys) in select2 dropdown select we trigger this controller when we're looking for the SSP term:

```
public function get_ssp(Request $request) {
    $term = $request->get('term');

    $ssp_list = SspCompanyList::where('ssp_company_name', 'LIKE', '%'. $term['term'] .'%')
        ->get(['ssp_company_id as id', 'ssp_company_name as text']);

    return ['results' => $ssp_list];

}
```

And then we process chosen ids in the controller after submitting and reloading the same page with rendered table. And we have to keep the values in the inline form above. Select2 in "multiple" mode has been configured this way:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#ssp').select2({
            width: '200px',
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            ajax: {
                url: '{{ route("get_ssp") }}',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "POST",
                quietMillis: 50,
                data: function (term) {
                    return {
                        term: term
                    };
                },
            },
        });
    });
```

but the problem is that select2 sends only ids in ssp_id[], not key-value items, and it's not possible to recover them from old() function as item names before sending.

So, I was trying to solve it in this way, by calling the model right in the blade view and selecting ssp names by its ids:

```
     <form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="{{route('ssp.report')}}">
        ...
        <select name="ssp_id[]" id="ssp" class="form-control-lg select2" multiple="multiple">
            @if (is_array(old('ssp_id')))
                @foreach (old('ssp_id') as $ssp_id)
                    {{ $ssp_name = \App\Models\SspCompanyList::select('ssp_company_name')->where('ssp_company_id', $ssp_id)->first()->ssp_company_name }}
                    <option value="{{ $ssp_name }}" selected="selected">{{ $ssp_name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            @endif
        </select>
     ...
     </form>
```

and after first reload it actually works and preserves all ssp names being selected before the first page reload, but after second attempt to select values for ssp below on the same page and submitting the form, laravel returns this error:

> Trying to get property 'ssp_company_name' of non-object (View:
> /home/pavel/projects/dsp/resources/views/dsp/index.blade.php)

So, why first time it's working and second time it isn't? Should we treat it in the other manner for select2 and add these old values via js, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem was in the following:

Before:

```
            <option value="{{ $ssp_name }}" selected="selected">{{ $ssp_name }}</option>
```

And after:

```
            <option value="{{ $ssp_id }}" selected="selected">{{ $ssp_name }}</option>
```